# Keeping track of global variables in recursive functions

Tags: lisp

I've been struggling with this question for the past few hours, scoured the internet for help, and I still can't seem to figure it out.

The question is simple:

Write a recursive program (in lisp) that takes a list and returns the number of 'a atoms in the list.

From the research I've done, it seems like LISP has an implicit counter in it, where if you just do (+ 1) it will keep track? Is this off?

Please help, I'm pretty frustrated...

Comment: nope, can only pass it a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea here is not to use a global variable, but instead to keep the count "in the stack".

Here's a Scheme solution. I'm sure you'll be able to convert this to whatever Lisp dialect you're using:

```
(define (count-a lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) 0)
        ((eq? (car lst) 'a) (+ (count-a (cdr lst)) 1))
        (else (count-a (cdr lst)))))
```

If that's not DRY enough for you, here's a more condensed version:

```
(define (count-a lst)
  (if (null? lst) 0
      (+ (count-a (cdr lst)) (if (eq? (car lst) 'a) 1 0))))
```

Comment: sorry, but I can't seem to get this right with a cond statement in my IDE (using allegro)

(defun get-a-count (x)
  (cond
   ((null x) 0
    ((eql (car x) 'a) (+ 1 (get-a-count (cdr x)))) 
    (t (+ 0 (get-a-count (cdr x)))))))

If you can see any glaring mistakes in my code, please let me know!!!

Comment: NEVERMIND figured it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have a counter carry along in a parameter.  I haven't used LISP in forever but just a simple (+ counterName 1) as a parameter should keep track. Don't forget to throw it a starting value though.

Comment: ok, but my issue is that the function needs to be recursive, and it seems that each time i give the recursive call, my counter variable returns to whatever I decided to initialize it to...

Is there a way to have a counter with recursive functions, in general?

Comment: You only need to give it a value the first call.  If you need the count and a different return value of the function you'll need to put them in a list at your stopping condition.